# What is Instances and Users Impacted in Crash Reprting of Firebase Console?

Tags: android, firebase, crash-reports, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using Firebase for Android application where I can see crash statistics. Can someone tell me what are the two checkboxes( shown in the below screenshot ) for?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Instances' is the total number of crashes that have taken place within your app.

'Users impacted' is how many users have experienced these crashes.

Comment: Thanks @RandomyzeEverything